# Does a COM DLL have to be compiled and registered for each bit edition?

Tags: dll, google-api, com, regasm

Is it OK for a COM DLL to be compiled as **AnyCPU** and work with both 32 bit and 64 bit applications?

Yesterday I started writing a C# COM DLL so that my MFC project could use the DLL. The DLL itself is for using the GMail API.

Initially I was compiling the DLL as either **x86** or **x64** and both of my executables were running fine.

Then I decided to change the DLL to compile as **AnyCPU** and now when my program runs it says **Class not registered**.

Does the DLL have to be compiled for each Bit edition then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can keep the .DLL compiled as "Any CPU" (in fact I certainly recommend it as long as you can), but you must register it in each version of the registry, so for example using [regasm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/regasm-exe-assembly-registration-tool):

64-bit:

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe ClassLibrary1.dll /codebase /tlb
```

32-bit:

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe ClassLibrary1.dll /codebase /tlb
```

Comment: Ok. But the registering is done by VS during compile. So why does my other app say class not registered?

Comment: Are there configurations when this would fail?

Comment: @AndrewTruckle - AFAIK, VS registration only works on your dev machine and only supports HKLM registration (not HKCU). This is a pretty useless and misleading feature IMHO.